# vuejs how to get index of child from child method

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have component:

```
Vue.component('child', {
    template : '#child-tpl',
    props    : {
        child : Object
        }
    },
    methods : {
        index : function () {
            return ???; // current index
        }
    }
});
```

This children can be reorder/remove/add dinamically. Need store actual current index of this children.
How to get current index for target child of parent children array?

Comment: Can you add code where child is being used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass index in as a prop. The index is coming from somewhere outside the child, so the child should receive it as a prop. There should not be any methods in a child that query parents for information. Everything a child needs from outside itself should be passed to it as props.

In the snippet below, the index is conveniently provided by the `v-for`.

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  template: '#child-tpl',
  props: ['child', 'index']
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    children: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
  },
  methods: {
    reverse: function () {
      this.children.reverse();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<template id="child-tpl">
<div>I'm {{child}}, {{index}}</div>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <child v-for="(child, index) in children" :child="child" :index="index"></child>
  <button @click="reverse">Reverse</button>
</div>
```